# Stm32CubeIDE can't flash because of arm-eabi-gcc

Tags: gcc, archlinux, stm32cubeide

I'm on Archlinux trying to flash a Nucleo STM32F446 board using STM32CubeIDE.
While running an example code (correctly build without problem), i get this error :
[image]

The quite not fun fact is that the command "arm-none-eabi-gdb --version" works well when i launch it on terminal.
And the same way, the file "libncurses.so.5" is linked in /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5 :
[image]

well, i'm lost here. i don't know what more to do. Even if i already checked a few forums, i know i'm not the only one with this issue.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Well, kinda figured it out,
an AUR package can solve the problem : ncurses5-compat-libs
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/
Download this package after removing the handmades links helps removing thins error.
Unfortunately, an other error, which seems to come from the code of the package itselfs pops up instead :

[image]

But i will create an other topic specifically on this one.
Have a great day, hope it works well for you !